# XMLHttpRequest for html page on web server but not in development

Tags: javascript, html, xml, rss

I have a web page which needs to load two separate rss feeds and display them in a ticker. The page loads and runs fine on my own machine but when I put it on our apache web server, it doesn't load anything.  When I open up the debug console, it shows the following error (in Safari 5.0.2):

NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occured in synchronous requests

How can I fix this?

Here's the basic outline of the javascript methods for loading the rss feeds.

```
function init() {
        // get RSS forecast
        getRSS("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=63211");
        getRSS("http://webserver.com/reader.xml");
    }

function getRSS (url) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlobject=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    // code to process response here...
    }
```

Comment: 1. I think you have the title of your question backwards 2. What happens when you load the problematic url into your browser manually?

Comment: If you set it to true instead of false and use the onreadystatechange, what is the http status/statusText?

Comment: Yeah, I thought I had fixed the title after I posted it but it's back to the way it was.  When I set the flag to true, it doesn't work at all, even on the Dev machine. StatusText is OK, statusText is 200.  I'm not sure how to use onreadystatechange though.

Comment: I also get a null error:  TypeError: Result of expression 'xmlobject' [null] is not an object.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that JavaScript has the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) so you can not grab content from another domain.

Comment: Assuming of course that the dev setup is not accessible via 'webserver.com'.  When I work in my dev environment I often use the host file to override the DNS entry for my domain, so that when I access mydomain.tld I am directed to the dev box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Neither the yahoo RSS feed (obviously) nor 'webserver.com' are hosted on the web server I'm trying to deploy on (just to be clear).  I didn't set up anything special on my dev machine to override anything so I'm puzzled as to why it would work there based on what you've said.  Isn't it possible to simply just consume RSS feeds like this via html?  I thought that's what XMLHttpRequest was for.

Comment: If you want to fetch stuff cross domain, some browser support CORS, but the easiest solution is to make a proxy on your server.

Comment: I looked into the CORS and tried: if("withCredentials" in xmlhttp) but it didn't work.  When you say "make a proxy on your server" could you give a little bit more detail on what is involved with going that route?

Comment: What do you run on the server? cgi, .net, java, php, etc

Comment: It's a 10.5 Mac Server.  It has options for setting up proxies in the server admin app but I've never done it.

Comment: technically, its the browser that is enforcing the same origin policy.  The language itself doesn't care.  You can turn the policy off in various ways on different browsers.